# VB.NET ComboBox SelectedIndex from MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

so I have done with show data form my database MySQL to ComboBox.. I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub Get_Product()
    Connection()

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM product, writer, publisher WHERE product.writer = writer.writer AND product.publisher = publisher.publisher AND code = " & throwCode & " ORDER BY code"

    Dim queryWriter As String = "SELECT DISTINCT writer, writer_name FROM writer ORDER BY writer_name"
    Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(queryWriter, conn)
    Dim dataSet As New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "writer")

    Try
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        While reader.Read
            TextBoxISBN.Text = reader("isbn")
            TextBoxTitle.Text = reader("title")
            TextBoxPage.Text = reader("page")

            With (ComboBoxWriter)
                .Items.Add("Select")
                .DataSource = dataSet.Tables("writer")
                .DisplayMember = "writer_name"
                .ValueMember = "writer"
                .SelectedIndex = 0 **// Give atention to this code**
            End With

            TextBoxYear.Text = reader("year")
            TextBoxCategory.Text = reader("category")
            TextBoxCallNumber.Text = reader("call_number")
            TextBoxWeight.Text = reader("weight")
            TextBoxPurchasePrice.Text = reader("purchase_price")
            TextBoxSellingPrice.Text = reader("selling_price")
            TextBoxDiscount.Text = reader("discount")
            TextBoxDescription.Text = reader("description")
            TextBoxTag.Text = reader("tag")

            TextBoxPusatPenerbit.Text = reader("pusat_penerbit")
            TextBoxMrican.Text = reader("mrican")
            TextBoxPaingan.Text = reader("paingan")

            If (Not IsDBNull(reader("picture"))) Then
                Dim byteImage() As Byte = reader("picture")
                Dim tempImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteImage)
                PictureBoxPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(tempImage)
            End If
        End While

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In my code, I give some comment and bold to show you what I want to do.

So I have a writer code in product an writer code in writer (writer code named as writer), and I join the table to show writer name from writer code. But in ComboBox I want to show all of writer for editing but the default value is index of the writer that same like in product table.

## 1

[image]

## 2

[image]

If you see my first image that have a writer name Sutarjo Adisusilo but when I view it and want to use it as a default value in combobox that show A. Kardiyat Wiharyanto as indexvalue number 0..

I need help how to change the default value to be same like the picture number 1

Thanks

Comment: `ComboBoxWriter.SelectedIndex = 0 **// Give atention to this code**` you always select the first item in your field

Comment: @romulus001 Yeah, I'm asking people in here to change that code, because I don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated this answer to an easier method. Double check the column names though.

```
ComboBoxWriter.SelectedIndex = ComboBoxWriter.FindStringExact(reader("writer_name"))
```

Comment: It won't work. I have change this code .SelectedIndex = 0 to be .SelectedItem = dataSet.Tables("writer").Select("writer_name='" & reader("writer_name") & "'").FirstOrDefault() and it still won't work for me. Result still choose the first index, please help